# Why both TreeView.SelectedValue and SelectedItem are the model instance instead of SelectedItem being a TreeViewItem?

Tags: wpf, treeview, .net-6.0, selecteditem, selectedvalue

In the `TreeView` that I work with, I need to determine the parent node of the currently selected node. It is bound to an `ObservableCollection<SomeModel>` in the viewmodel. When I inspect the currently selected node, both `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` point to the same instance of `SomeModel`. How can I find the parent node then?
Everything I read on `TreeView.SelectedItem` suggests to use `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` but it takes a `DependencyObject`, not a user's model, which is totally reasonable.
The binding is as follows:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeViewAvailable" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableSchemas}">
```

The collection in the viewmodel is as follows:

```
ObservableCollection<Models.Schema>? _availableSchemas;
public ObservableCollection<Models.Schema>? AvailableSchemas
{
    get => _availableSchemas;
    set
    {
        _availableSchemas = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }
}
```

The `Schema` model class contains `Tables` that we see in the screenshot:

```
public ObservableCollection<Table> Tables { get; set; } = new();
```

Having in the past worked with frameworks in which `SelectedItem` was always the GUI component's `ViewItem` and `SelectedValue` was the actual model, I do not understand whether something is wrong with the XAML binding and/or viewmodel/model or whether it is by design of WPF that `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` both are the instance of the model, which feels wrong.

[image]

I see answers on SO that instruct to rig models that themselves track parent-child relationships, and that is the definition of having to write boilerplate code. It cannot be that WPF has nothing for working with `TreeView` nodes.

This contradicts [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeview.selectedvalue?view=windowsdesktop-8.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.TreeView.SelectedValue)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) that clearly states that `SelectedItems` has to be of type `TreeViewItem`:

> To change the value of a selected item in a TreeView, use the
> SelectedItem property to access the TreeViewItem.

Comment: There is also `TreeViewItem selectedTVI = (TreeViewItem)myTreeView.SelectedItem;` in the [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem#examples) in the SelectedItem documentation. This is however clearly wrong. SelectedItem returns an element of the ItemsSource collection at the current hierarchy level. Only when you add TreeViewItems manually, a TreeViewItem is returned.

Comment: In addition to Clemens' explanation, I would like to point out that WPF was designed with a clear separation of data and data presentation in mind. In this sense you would usually bind data models to the `ItemsSource` and define a `DataTemplate` to describe the presentation of the data ([Microsoft learn: Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
).

Comment: An application is always data focused. When the user selects an item, you don't care about the UI elements. You want to know which *data* object was selected. Like any good application framework, WPF tries to promote good application design. The decision to separate data from data presentation leads to clean and testable applications. So, the design decision makes very much sense. Your quoted statement is correct in that it says that you don't  set the selected `TreeViewItem` (the data item container) directly. Instead, you select it by using the `SelectedItem` property.

Comment: Of course, you can always add item containers directly, but this is not recommended as this would e.g., disable performance features like UI virtualization that most ItemsControl subclasses support. WPF allows you to use the controls the classic way where your presentation logic has to deal with data containers (by adding item containers like ListBoxItem directly) or you can use the same control the modern way where UI and data is strictly separated e.g. DataTemplate and data item). This means you can decide whether you want SelectedItem to return the item container or the item (recommended).